# Invalid conversion error with int arrays

Tags: c++, arrays

I have an assignment to get command line arguments from a user - the user inputs two ints to define the rows and columns of a dynamic array. The array is then filled with random numbers. I can't seem to create the array, as I keep getting invalid conversion errors no matter what I try. Can anyone clear up what I'm misunderstanding here?

I've reproduced the relevant code and error message per line below:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

/* Cut out code irrelevant to question that gets the arguments 
   to define columns and rows. This part works fine. */

    int * array = new int[rows];

    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
            array[i] = new int[columns];  // error: invalid conversion from ‘int*’ to ‘int’

    }

    int * pointer = array;

    array = randomArray(pointer, rows, columns);

    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
                    cout << array[i][j] + " " << endl;  // error: invalid types ‘int[int]’ for array subscript

            }
    }

    return 0;

}


int* randomArray(int array[], int rows, int columns) {

    srand (time(0));

    for (i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
                    int random = rand() % 100;
                    array[i][j] = random; // error: invalid types ‘int[int]’ for array subscript
            }
    }
    return array;

    for (i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
            delete[] array[rows];
    }
    delete[] array; // error: type ‘int’ argument given to ‘delete’, expected pointer
}
```

I've managed to clean up most of the errors so far but I can't seem to fix these last ones. I know I'm missing something important about 2d arrays. Any tips?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want `array` to be an array of pointers to `int` arrays so

```
int * array = new int[rows];
```

should be

```
int ** array = new int*[rows];
```

and

```
int* randomArray(int array[], int rows, int columns)
```

would become

```
int** randomArray(int *array[], int rows, int columns)
```

or, as pointed out by WhozCraig,

```
void randomArray(int *array[], int rows, int columns)
```

since the return value isn't required.

Alternatively, if it doesn't violate constraints of your assignment, you could use `std::vector` instead

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> array;
```

Comment: +1 Note: once implemented this way, the return value of `randomArray` is pointless. If `randomArray()` actually *allocated* the array and only took the two dimensions as parameters, it would obviously be required.

Comment: @WhozCraig Thanks, I hadn't checked that the implementation of the function required the current signature.  I've noted this in my answer now.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I'm still having a few problems getting it to compile... I need to be able to pass this array to the randomArray function but I can't seem to get it to work. I created the int * pointer as a dummy to pass to the function, but once I implemented your suggestions, now I get this error when initializing it:  cannot convert ‘int*’ to ‘int**’ for argument ‘1’ to ‘void randomArray(int**, int, int)’ and this error when using it as a parameter: error: cannot convert ‘int*’ to ‘int**’ for argument ‘1’ to ‘void randomArray(int**, int, int)’

Comment: You need to pass the address of a `int*` variable (using the `&` operator) to have it treated as `int**`